How to swap tune to blend with the music's without drifting
I am a bass and also singer
Sometimes when singing something deep like bass and the likes, the music's tune will go higher and higher compelling me to swap to something less deep like treble. I despise this as it makes my voice less intrepid.
How can I tackle this problem? Is it possible to sing deeply while the music's tune is going high?

Does the word "bass" mean an instrument sometimes in this question, as well as a vocal range? Are you talking about singing along with an instrumental bass line? Are you talking about singing the melody of a song but trying to fit it to your range? Are you singing along to a recording, or making music by yourself? Are you talking about choir music with multiple vocal parts? Please explain a bit more. The short answer is "Yes, there are often ways to sing and stay within your range."

I’m a bass and also a singer ... Some basses might feel offended ...

@Lazy Some other basses would appreciate it...

@musicamante In our local music school we have stickers on the windows saying please keep the windows shut while singing and making music ...

I'll go ahead and answer the part of this question that's clear to me. I'm not sure whether you play bass and are singing along with a bass line, or are simply singing a vocal line. Either way, the problem seems to be that you're singing music that rises out of your comfortable range and want to know what you can do to stay in your range. There are two easy suggestions: change the key, or sing harmony.
If you're singing along to someone else's recording, or if you're singing along with a song that's been written down, say in tab or chord symbols, then you're singing in a key that the original singer picked to fit their voice. It might not be the best one for yours. If the song doesn't use the deepest part of your range, just the middle and top, then just change to a lower key. Just a step or two can make a big difference; e.g., if the song is in C, try changing it to A. That's easier said than done; if you're singing along to a recording, it means changing the pitch; you can't do that in most simple audio players, but you can in fancier apps like DAWs. If you're playing from sheet music, you can often find a version in a different key just by searching, or some music sites can transpose automatically.
Now, if the song has a very wide range—if it goes down to the bottom of your range and up into a range you're not comfortable with—then changing the key won't work. When there's a melody you can't sing comfortably... you can just not sing the melody. Sing a "harmony line"—lower notes that sound good with the melody because they come from the same chords. This is too complicated a skill to explain from scratch here, but you can get a pretty good idea by finding any song that has background harmony vocals, especially ones lower than the main singer. There are also plenty of youtube videos to teach harmony parts for popular songs. By practicing on well-known songs, you should be able to make up harmony parts to any song. When in doubt, you could even simply steal the notes from the bass (instrument).
